# With an excess supply of nutrients, in how much time will the number of algae cells double in full sun?

Tags: cell-division, growth

I am growing algae in a container in my roof. It gets sunlight for the whole day as there are no clouds nowadays in my area. There is no lack of nutrients as I am constantly adding water mixed with organic waste. The dirt visible in the photos is from manure, which I added as fertilizer.

The water has become green and algae is deposited on top covering almost all of the surface area. There are no threads, so it is not filamentous.

Since there are probably several species of algae in it which I don't know, please tell me the doubling time of most common species.

Also, is there anything I can do to hasten the production of cells?

Below are pictures of the culture, as asked for.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it is possible to answer this question.

Comment: Please go through the articles http://www.marine.csiro.au/microalgae/methods/Growth%20rate.htm and http://eprints.cmfri.org.in/400/1/Article_09.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming this a Blue Green Algae(BGA) [Identify your algae](http://publications.gc.ca/collections/collection_2011/agr/A125-8-2-2011-eng.pdf)

Growth rate for N1, N2 biomass at t1 and t2 time respectively, can be give as,

Growth rate:   $K'$ = $\ln \frac{(N_2 / N_1)}{(t_2 - t_1)}$

[image]
<sub>(source: [csiro.au](http://www.marine.csiro.au/microalgae/methods/support%20or%20original%20files/Growth2.gif))</sub>

So, by this equation it is easy to calculate the doubling time of your algae.

[image]

For BGA normal doubling time is 6-8 hours.$^2$

Source:

1. http://www.marine.csiro.au/microalgae/methods/Growth%20rate.htm
2. https://sites.google.com/site/biomonstaaar/algae